# perform click event of a site's button from code

Tags: android, webview, onclick

After trying all afternoon and several sites for the answers to my questions and not be able to do it, I gave up and I place all my hopes in this question now appeal to you.

I want to create an application that pressing a button, it running the event click of a button of a site.

I would ask you a complete code example of an application with a button and a TextView, where pressing the button it starts a search on google of the text in the TextView..

Sorry for the bad english, this is a google translate from italian;)

THANKS YOU

Comment: First of all, you won't be able to click on a button across the domains. A lot of sites like google.com will not even load into your iframe (I'm assuming that you can loading it into an iframe when you say clicking on a button of a site).

Maybe clarify your question a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <form method="get" action="http://www.google.co.uk/search">
        <input name="q"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

Is the only thing i can think you are asking for?